# Pytorch DataLoader changes dict return values

Tags: python, json, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

Given a Pytorch dataset that reads a JSON file as such:

```
import csv

from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader2, DataLoader

class MyDataset(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, jsonfilename):
        self.filename = jsonfilename

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.filename) as fin:
            reader = csv.reader(fin)
            headers = next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                yield dict(zip(headers, line))
                
content = """imagefile,label
train/0/16585.png,0
train/0/56789.png,0"""

with open('myfile.json', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(content)

ds = MyDataset("myfile.json")
```

When I loop through the dataset, the return values are dict of each line of the json, e.g.

```
ds = MyDataset("myfile.json")

for i in ds:
    print(i)
```

[out]:

```
{'imagefile': 'train/0/16585.png', 'label': '0'}
{'imagefile': 'train/0/56789.png', 'label': '0'}
```

But when I read the Dataset into a `DataLoader`, it returns the values of the dict as lists instead of the values themselves, e.g.

```
ds = MyDataset("myfile.json")
x = DataLoader(dataset=ds)

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

[out]:

```
{'imagefile': ['train/0/16585.png'], 'label': ['0']}
{'imagefile': ['train/0/56789.png'], 'label': ['0']}
```

#### Q (part1) : Why does the DataLoader changes the value of the dict to a list?

and also

#### Q (part2) : How to make the DataLoader return just the values of the dict instead of the list of value when running `__iter__` with the DataLoader? Is there some arguments/options to use in DataLoader to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the default collate behaviour in [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), which determines how data samples in a batch are merged. By default, the [`torch.utils.data.default_collate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.default_collate) collate function is used, which transforms mappings as:

> Mapping[K, V_i] -> Mapping[K, default_collate([V_1, V_2, …])]

and strings as:

> str -> str (unchanged)

Note that if you set `batch_size` to 2 in your example, you get:

```
{'imagefile': ['train/0/16585.png', 'train/0/56789.png'], 'label': ['0', '0']}
```

as a consequence of these transforms.

Assuming you do not need batching, you can get your desired output by disabling it by setting `batch_size=None`. More information on this here: [Loading Batched and Non-Batched Data](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#loading-batched-and-non-batched-data).

Comment: We posted similar answer at the same time =) The default `batch_size=1` is the main reason I was confused. Thanks for the details in the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

##### See @GoodDeeds' answer for details! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73824234/610569

---

The following answers are for TL;DR readers:

#### Q: Why does the DataLoader changes the value of the dict to a list?

A: Because there is an implicit assumption that the `__iter__` of `DataLoader` object should return a batch of data, not a single data.

#### Q (part2) : How to make the DataLoader return just the values of the dict instead of the list of value when running **iter** with the DataLoader? Is there some arguments/options to use in DataLoader to do this?

A: Due to the implicit batch returning behaviour, it's better to modify the return batch of data in the `{key: [value1, value2, ...]`, instead of trying to force `DataLoader` to return `{key: value1}`.

To better understand the batching assumption, try the `batch_size` argument:

```
x = DataLoader(dataset=ds, batch_size=2)

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

[out]:

```
{'imagefile': ['train/0/16585.png', 'train/0/56789.png'], 'label': ['0', '0']}
```